# Can't parse segment Firebase Token Python/Flask

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-authentication

I am currently building a small API project using Flask. I want to authenticate the request using Firebase Auth. I am using the verify_id_token function in a small middleware.

```
def check_token(f):
@wraps(f)
def wrap(*args,**kwargs):
    token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    if not token:
        return {'message': 'No token provided'},400
    try:
        user = auth.verify_id_token(token)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error verifying token: {e}')
        return {'message':'Invalid token provided.'},400
    else:
        request.user = user
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
return wrap
```

My code has been working properly but then for no reasons I started to have the following issue:

```
Error verifying token: Can't parse segment: b'\x05\xe6\xabz\xb7\xb2&\....
```

I have double check the token and I see no issues on that side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error,
I was sending Bearer TOKEN, I just needed to send TOKEN
Luck with it!

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reasons may be, that while making the API request, you are using "Bearer" with authorization in the request, but in the code, you are not using any bearer.

Although it's always better to use Bearer because of the security and other purposes while making a Firebase auth request. You can do it like this:

```
def check_token(f):
@wraps(f)
def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
    auth_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')

    if not auth_header:
        return {'message': 'No token provided'}, 400

    # Check if the header starts with 'Bearer '
    if not auth_header.startswith('Bearer '):
        return {'message': 'Bearer token required'}, 400

    # Extract the token by removing the 'Bearer ' prefix
    token = auth_header.split(' ', 1)[1]

    try:
        user = auth.verify_id_token(token)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error verifying token: {e}')
        return {'message': 'Invalid token provided.'}, 400
    else:
        request.user = user
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

return wrap
```

Comment: Just make sure the code block is well-formatted. Sometimes question authors make mistakes in their code formatting. When replying, please ensure that it is corrected.